# Dynamic SQL in Function / While Loop Insert into Table Variable with Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, dynamic

I've written the following query...but I am having a hard time converting it into a function because of a couple reasons...(1) because it contains dynamic SQL and I'm not sure if Functions allow dynamic SQL, and (2) because I am using a temp table to store the output data. I tried converting it to a table variable with no luck. The point of the query is to take any two datetime ranges and an increment type (month, day, year, hour, whatever) and spits out a table of date ranges that include the provided range.

The reason for the query is because I have to write a lot of reports for report server, and many times the report requests want break downs by hour, day, week, month, etc, and I constantly have to write the same query over and over to produce a table of date ranges. I use these tables to left join to so that my final output does not skip any date ranges in case there is no data for that range, it will still fill in zero's and graph/chart out properly.

I don't think there's any way to make this code work in a function, unless there is a completely different way to write it (EDIT, SEE UPDATE BELOW)...I'm sure I could go the long complex route of having some sort of long case statement that instead just had each increment type (second, minute, hour, day, week, month, quarter, year) and then I could eliminate the dynamic SQL. And maybe I could use recursive CTE's and eliminate the while loop. But I don't have any experience with those.

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DATETIME = '2017-01-01',
        @DateTo DATETIME = '2017-02-02 23:59:59.997',
        @Increment VARCHAR(20) = 'mm'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateRange') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DateRange --SELECT * FROM #DateRange
CREATE TABLE #DateRange (BeginDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

SELECT @SQL = '
    DECLARE @TargetDate DATETIME = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DateFrom, 121) + '''
    IF DATEDIFF('+ @Increment +', ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DateFrom, 121) + ''', ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DateTo, 121) + ''') > 2000 RETURN

    WHILE (1=1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #DateRange
        SELECT BeginDate = DATEADD('+ @Increment +', DATEDIFF('+ @Increment +', 0, @TargetDate)    , 0)
            , EndDate =    DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD('+ @Increment +', DATEDIFF('+ @Increment +', 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0))

        SET @TargetDate = DATEADD('+ @Increment +', 1, @TargetDate)
        IF @TargetDate > ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DateTo, 121) + ''' BREAK
    END'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT * FROM #DateRange
```

EDIT: Here's a modified version, not sure if this would be considered "better" but at least it eliminates the dynamic SQL, and I'm able to use it as a function.

EDIT2: since this runs quicker, I changed the limit to 5000 records returned. I also changed the direction it runs, so it starts from DateTo and works backwards. That way when it hits the limit, it just stops only going back so far. I also added some safety's, like checking the Increment (not sure what else to call it?) option values. I hate that giant case statement, but I don't see any other way to to do it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uf_DateRange (  
    @DateFrom DATETIME,
    @DateTo DATETIME,
    @Increment VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS @Return TABLE  (
    BeginDate       DATETIME,
    EndDate         DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Increment NOT IN ('year','yy','yyyy','quarter','qq','q','month','mm','m','week','wk','ww','day','dd','d','hour','hh','minute','mi','n','second','ss','s') RETURN

    DECLARE @TargetDate DATETIME = @DateTo,
            @LoopLimit INT = 5000,
            @Counter INT = 0

    DECLARE @DateRange TABLE (BeginDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME)

    WHILE (@Counter < @LoopLimit)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Return (BeginDate, EndDate)
        SELECT BeginDate    =   CASE WHEN @Increment IN ('year'   , 'yy', 'yyyy') THEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @TargetDate), 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('quarter', 'qq', 'q'   ) THEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @TargetDate), 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('month'  , 'mm', 'm'   ) THEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @TargetDate), 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('week'   , 'wk', 'ww'  ) THEN DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, @TargetDate), 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('day'    , 'dd', 'd'   ) THEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @TargetDate), 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('hour'   , 'hh'        ) THEN DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, @TargetDate), 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('minute' , 'mi', 'n'   ) THEN DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @TargetDate), 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('second' , 'ss', 's'   ) THEN DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(ss, 0, @TargetDate), 0)
                                END
            , EndDate       =   DATEADD(ms, -3,
                                CASE WHEN @Increment IN ('year'   , 'yy', 'yyyy') THEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('quarter', 'qq', 'q'   ) THEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('month'  , 'mm', 'm'   ) THEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('week'   , 'wk', 'ww'  ) THEN DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('day'    , 'dd', 'd'   ) THEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('hour'   , 'hh'        ) THEN DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('minute' , 'mi', 'n'   ) THEN DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('second' , 'ss', 's'   ) THEN DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(ss, 0, @TargetDate) + 1, 0)
                                END)        
        SET @TargetDate     =   CASE WHEN @Increment IN ('year'   , 'yy', 'yyyy') THEN DATEADD(yy, -1, @TargetDate)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('quarter', 'qq', 'q'   ) THEN DATEADD(qq, -1, @TargetDate)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('month'  , 'mm', 'm'   ) THEN DATEADD(mm, -1, @TargetDate)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('week'   , 'wk', 'ww'  ) THEN DATEADD(ww, -1, @TargetDate)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('day'    , 'dd', 'd'   ) THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @TargetDate)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('hour'   , 'hh'        ) THEN DATEADD(hh, -1, @TargetDate)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('minute' , 'mi', 'n'   ) THEN DATEADD(mi, -1, @TargetDate)
                                     WHEN @Increment IN ('second' , 'ss', 's'   ) THEN DATEADD(ss, -1, @TargetDate)
                                END
        IF @TargetDate > @DateTo BREAK
        SET @Counter += 1
    END

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into a bunch of limitations here. It is my understanding that a function cannot execute a sproc so that is a big show-stopper. Also, you can't use a function to do an INSERT (or UPDATE or DELETE) so there's another big problem.

Is there a specific reason you can't leave it as a procedure?

Comment: I was able to eliminate the dynamic sql by using an ugly case statement. See my update to the original post.

I don't like using stored procedures when the point of the code is to output data to be used in another query. In my brain, I see table valued functions as a sort of parameterized view.

When you want data out of a proc, you need to know the entire output of the proc, and all of the datatypes and then create a table for the proc to output the data to. With a function, you can just SELECT * FROM [Function], just like you would with a table. Way easier to use.

Comment: You explicitly cannot do an INSERT in a UDF so this isn't going to work for you. A table type may work in this case, which is very similar to a TEMP table.

Comment: Yeah, I know it won't work, but see my latest update, as ugly as it is, that does work and I've been using it. You can't do an insert into a table, but table variables you can.